# How to make the sql database installer setup in visual studio use Windows Authentication?

Tags: database, installation, setup-deployment

I have been following this tutorial to install the database script using a setup. But it only works for the SQL login credentials.

> [Walkthrough: Using a Custom Action to Create a Database at Installation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110314045713/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk.aspx)

How do I make this work with Windows Authentication credentials?

Comment: The link is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

For C# you can start below: See if you can get a connection to open.
If you are not using localhost change it to server address.

```
public class SQLconn{
    public  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=xxx;" +
                                       "password=xxx;server=localhost;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=dbname; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
    public void connect(){
      try {
         myConnection.Open();
      }catch (Exception e){
         MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
      }
    }
}
```